# how can I fix time duration to fill up a form

Tags: php, jquery, forms, time

how can I fix time duration to fill up a form, the form will submit auto end of the time and never can be back to the form while the time running or at the end...

Comment: I have posted the updated code.Hope atleast this helps you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to keep a timer in your html, and set the time as your wish.Just download .js files from these links

[Link 1](http://www.gieson.com/Library/projects/utilities/countdown/)

[Link 2](http://www.timeanddate.com/clocks/freecountdown.html)

Hope this helps!!

**EDIT:-**

Here is the link for the code that that contains almost all the requirements you want!

[CountDownTimer](https://github.com/yenumulasudhirkumar/CountDownTimer)

Click download zip to get the code and try to run it.There may be some exceptions, but this will be helpful for you!

Comment: thanks a lot, but when I refresh the page it start again from the beginning, how could I prevent this?

Comment: I don't know whether it will work or not but here is the idea!!
declare a variable boolean flag=true; if the page is loaded for set the flag=false. show the timer only when flag is true. Just let me know if this works

Comment: Try to accept the answer if your 1st question is solved, because it may be useful for others

Comment: thanks for your reply, but I am not friendly with your answer. I need  to make a page where a form will get only 4 minutes to fill up and not refreshable at the moment. when the time expires it will auto submit and never can back..... I have a general knowledge in php and jquery but not expert....  please help me to do the program work

Comment: Thanks a lot, its done. very thanks for your patient co-operation

Comment: Thanks, can u pls accept the answer if every thing is solved

Comment: its almost done but at last I am facing a problem, the form is counting the minutes not seconds. Say, the form started at  03:55:40, so it need to be stop at 03:57:40 (for 2 minutes), but it stop at 03:57:00, the second is not counting in last minute..... could you please get a solution......

Comment: Your solution lies between these lines:-

1) IN index.php --> $min=date("i", strtotime("+2 minutes"));

2)In form.php updateclock() --> if(currentMinutes>=minlimit||currentHours>hourlimit)
 {

use sec instead of min.Try to edit these lines.you will get easily if u  first understand the code.Best of luck

Comment: @Nafees Ahmed Try to edit your question so that it will be helpful for others also