# FlipClock time value from MySQL database and no reset on refresh

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, flipclock

I am using FlipClock reverse minute counter on my PHP page. As of now I am hard-coding the time (the time is hard-coded to 5 minutes in the example). But I want to fetch the value from the MySQL database and show it on the screen, instead of the hard-coded value. Also, when I refresh the page, the counter starts all over again. I don't want that to happen. The counter should not reset even if the page refreshes. How do I tweak my code. Any help...

My code is:

PHP code:

```
<div class="your-clock"></div>
```

Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var clock;

$(document).ready(function() {

  clock = $('.your-clock').FlipClock(300, {
        countdown: true,
        clockFace: 'MinuteCounter'

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Answer (score 1):

I would save the start value with a DateTime (file or database).
Then with PHP get this value, make difference with current time and write it in your jQuery script.

PHP is executed before (on server) javascript (on client) so just write the value in your javascript with PHP.

Comment: This is how I would do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solutions(may not be the best one):-

Create two php files, In the first file collect the value of time from the database and store in some variable then using this code send the variable value to second php file using this code.

```
header("Location:file2.php?time=$time");
```

Doing this way even if you refresh the file your time value won't get updated.

Here is the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560869/how-can-i-fix-time-duration-to-fill-up-a-form/26561210#26561210) who has the similar problem and the solution for the problem is [here](https://github.com/yenumulasudhirkumar/CountDownTimer/archive/master.zip)